# Create heatmap from covariance matrix with pre-specified hierarchical tree dendrogram in R

Tags: r, heatmap, pheatmap, complexheatmap

For my real data analysis, I calculate hierarchical tree from a custom algorithm based on a covariance matrix. Now I want to create a heatmap of this covariance matrix with the custom dendrogram plotted along with the covariance matrix.

Here is a short example:

```
# Create a custom dendrogram with four clusters named A to D.
hclust <- list()
hclust$merge <- matrix(c(-1,    -2,
                         -3,     -4,
                          1,     2), ncol = 2, byrow = T)
hclust$height <- c(0.2, 0.4, 0.8) 
hclust$order <- 1:4              # order of leaves(trivial if hand-entered)
hclust$labels <- LETTERS[1:4]    # labels of leaves
class(hclust) <- "hclust"        # make it an hclust object
plot(hclust) 

# Simulate a 10*10 covariance matrix.
covMat <- matrix(rnorm(100), 10)

# Plot the heatmap where rows 1-2 belong to cluster A, 3-5 belong to cluster B, 6-7 belong to cluster C, and 8-10 belong to cluster D.
library(pheatmap)
pheatmap(covMat, distfun = function(x) x, scale = "none", 
         cluster_rows = hclust, cluster_cols = FALSE, display_numbers = F)
```

The resultant heatmap contains only four rows, which is not what I want as specified above. I know the `pheatmap(covMat, ...)` line must be wrong since I did not specify which rows of the covariance matrix belong to which cluster.

The covariance matrix for my real data has thousands of rows. So I want the solution to be general. Additionally, I wish to create the heatmap in R, preferrably using pheatmap, tidyHeatmap, or ComplexHeatmap. Other packages are also welcome.